# Oracle-How to interpret the result of my statistcs of AUTOTRACE

Tags: oracle, query-performance

I have statistis of autotrace, before and after the modification of my query.

Does this statistics imply some significant performance improvements?

The statistics Before/After as below.

```
                                       BEFORE    AFTER
                                       -----     -----
recursive calls                            5         3
db block gets                             16         8
consistent gets                           45        44
physical reads                             2         1
redo size                               1156       600
bytes sent via SQL*Net to client         624       624
bytes received via SQL*Net from client   519       519
SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client          2         2
sorts (memory)                             0         1
sorts (disk)                               0         0
rows processed                             1         1
```

Comment: The most important thing to look at is `consistent gets` and they didn't really get smaller

Comment: How much time between the BEFORE and AFTER runs? It's quite possible you're just seeing the effect of a warm cache: some of the data you needed was still in memory, so the database didn't have to read it from disk again.

Answer (score 1):

I won't read too much into it just by the Auto-trace information. You might also want to check the explain plan and the actual run time of query to see if performance has improved, Also ensure that you have gathered latest stats on all of your tables being used in the query.